Visualizing LiDAR image
I am new to QGIS and I am using QGIS 3.22 on a Windows 10 OS.
After importing the .laz file into QGIS (with the "Add point cloud" command) I can only seea square whose boundaries are made of a red dashed line.
Am I missing any step?

That square with red dashed lines means your point cloud has been imported. How large is the point cloud? Can you post a link to it?

we are talking about 105MB
here is a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ogdpd7f3D_fLViupCgvsbrdCGMoTvmNF/view?usp=drive_link

There's something about that file that QGIS doesn't like. Re-save it in CloudCompare and then you can visualize more than just the boundary.

The downloaded .laz file works for me without issues by adding data with drag'n'drop. I am using QGIS from OSGeo4W, version 3.37.0

@user30184, Looks like maybe a version problem. I get same as Antonio with QGIS 3.22.16

What do you have as rendering mode in Layer properties - Symbology? One option is "Extent Only" and that shows only the outline. My QGIS had "RGB" as default.

I changed the Symbology to RGB but nothing changed.

I also put the file through CloudCompare and although I can visualize it there, the content of the resulting saved file isn't visible after importing it into QGIS

ok, I tried to open the laz file with version 3.34.6 LTR and exactly the same problem appears.

Re-saving the LAZ in CloudCompare, I was able to open it without problem in my QGIS 3.22.16. Seems to be a problem with "Point Size". Changing/repairing the Point Size with LASTools to something other than 3 should also work.

@Pointdump, how do I do this? I opened LASTools but do not see any process that does what you suggest (I never used LASTools) Which of the processes within the suite should I use?

Antonio, I wasn't able to fix with LASTools. Only re-saving in CloudCompare worked. Have you tried upgrading QGIS?

As I said above I used QGIS 3.34.6 or shpuld I go for 3.7?
As for CC which file extension did you use to save the file? I see that there are 2 or 3 possibilities: LAS 1.3 orr LAS 1.4, There is LAS cloud. But none of these produced a file that allowed me to visualize the content. Also the LAs Cloud format/extension produces a file in DWG true view format, not suitable to be loaded as a point cloud layer

Hi I eventually managed to import the file correctly. I also installed QGIS 3.36, but I am not 100% sure how that happened though, because the first attempst with this newer version also failed. What I did was to change the points' size within to 3 initially but then I switched again to 1 and worked as well.

For me opening the .laz file into QGIS 3.37.0 on Windows happens in two steps:

When the .laz file is added into the map QGIS shows first only an outline, but QGIS also begins immediately a process to index the data.




Indexing seems to create a new cloud optimized point cloud file "PNOA_2016_CAT_484-4680_ORT-CLA-COL.copc.laz" into the source folder. The QGIS screen is flashing and the point cloud appears rendered with colors. That happens automatically.



I tried importing a different .laz file (with similar information than the one shared but older) and it worked instantly. So for some reason the indexing process explained in the answer doesn't start for this file. I wonder why this is the case. I also shut down QGIS and started it again to no avail.

Antonio, upgrade your QGIS to 3.37.0 like @user30184 has.

I am going to upgrade. However the latest version available (that I can find) is 3.36.2 Maidenhead, not 3.37

That's correct, I am using the development version (nightly) that I have installed with the OSGeo4W installer.

So, I guess having upgraded to 3.36 and re-saving with CloudCompare have helped importing correctly the lidar file into QGIS.
